# Logging from a dll, retrieve calling method name above log.put()

Tags: c#, dll

so I am looking to log in a dll, that will record some automatically generated information each time the log.put is called. I cannot seem to get the calling method name from within the dll, regardless of using the stack trace...

```
void main() {
    log.put(Severity.information, "this is a test");
}



//inside dll

  Log.put(Enum s, string msg = ""){
        StackTrace st = new StackTrace(new StackFrame(true)); //get stacktrace
//returns put as expected
        string caller = st.GetFrame(0).GetMethod().ToString(); 
//returns put not expected, I was expecting main
        string caller2 = st.GetFrame(st.FrameCount - 1).GetMethod().ToString(); 
//throws null reference
        string caller3 = st.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().ToString(); 
}
```

basically, I really dont want to have to hardcode every method name and a dateTime call in all my catch statements, I would like to just call it and have it recorded.

Is this possible?

Comment: @Dzyann ill update above, but that actually throws a null reference expceotion

Comment: Sorry, I meant new StackFrame(1).GetMethod(), does that work? => Check here, you want to pass 1 because you want one frame above => http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws7f30w6(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: As you can see here, StackFrame(true) gives the information for the current level => http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3732axf(v=vs.110).aspx